# My cat attacks me if I breath loudly close to her

Tags: cats, aggression

After sterilization my cat (she's about 10 months old) became a bit aggressive and very hyperactive, which I thought might be caused as her hormones are getting back to the place after the surgery.

But recently I noticed that whenever I exhale loudly while petting her she bites, and even scratch my face. She's also getting mad when I don't give her cat treat as regular food, anything else she won't eat and is just running around and doing stuff she isn't allowed to do (such as jumping on a table, on the kitchen sink, to the flowers, which she's been taught not to do it).

Today I had a same problem with feeding her, and as she jumped on the table once again I picked her up, and tried to speak to her, tho she can't understand me, I thought a bit of calm voice would help her as it does sometimes, and asi had her up in my arms, I sighed and she bit my nose and scratched my eye, even when I stood quiet and tried to not to breath at all, shed still hear me and keep attacking me.

I can't afford any special training for her, so I thought maybe here I'd get answers what to do.

Comment: When you picked her up, were you talking to her about why she shouldn't get on the table? Do you scold her as a form of discipline? I heard that taking a calm but stern tone might have an effect on dogs, but it is completely wasted on cats.

Comment: @C.Koca My cats definitely react differently based on my tone of voice.

Comment: @StephenS I don't know. The cats I took care understood that I am upset but they refused the discipline. They'd still keep jumping on the kitchen counter even though they know I am upset:)

Comment: @C.Koca Mine misbehave, but when I yell at them, they stop and wait until I’m gone to do it again. Clever!

Answer (score 2):

There is a fundamental difference between cats and dogs. You can teach a dog not to go on the table, but a cat is very likely to ignore the training and to it anyways.

Also, in natural cat body language, looking a cat right in the eyes is a form of aggression and means the same as growling for a dog. When you picked her up and spoke to her, you probably looked her in the eyes. Even though your voice was calm, your body language was very aggressive and she fought you back. The same might happen when you pet her. If you look her in the eyes while petting, she doesn't scratch you because you breath, but because she thinks you might attack her first.

The first thing you should do is:
Whenever you see her, do the "lazy cat blink" at her. I'm sure you've seen a cat blink her eyes very slowly. That's also cat body language, but it means the opposite of looking her in the eyes: "I'm your friend. I don't want a fight." Speak to her with your gestures by blinking your eyes the same way. It may take some time, but if you do that every time you see her, she should calm down and trust you more.

Another possible cause of her aggression is pain. I don't know how long ago the operation was, but she might still feel pain, especially when you pick her up. Pain makes cats aggressive. You should gently try to look at her incision to see if it heals well or is inflamed. If it is already healed, it might be worth to have her checked by the vet again. Maybe there is some scar tissue that causes her pain or a completely unrelated problem.